# Repaint JPanel during Thread algorithm working

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, parallel-processing, jpanel

Ok, I wrote MCVE as you wanted. The point is I'm traing to repaint MazePanel from another thread (RecursiveThread), but it doesn't work. JPanel is repainted only when RecursiveThread end work...

MCVE:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.sun.prism.Graphics;

public class Main {

public static Gui gui;
public static int[] directionArray = {0, 1, 2, 3};
public static int[][] maze = {
    {2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2},
    {2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2},
    {2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2},
    {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2},
    {2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2}
};
public static RecursiveAlgorithm recursiveAlgorithm;
public static Thread alghoritmThread;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            gui = new Gui();
        }
    });
}
}

class MazePanel extends JPanel {

private int rows;
private int columns;



@Override
protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    rows = Main.maze.length;
    columns = Main.maze[0].length;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

        for (int  c = 0; c < columns; c++) {

            switch (Main.maze[r][c]) {
                case 0:
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            g.fillRect(c * 64, r * 64, 64, 64);
        }
    }
}



public void paint(Graphics g) {


}
}

class GuiActionListener implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if (event.getSource() == Gui.startButton) {

        Main.recursiveAlgorithm = new RecursiveAlgorithm();
        Main.alghoritmThread = new Thread(Main.recursiveAlgorithm);
        Main.alghoritmThread.run();
    }
}
}

class Gui extends JFrame {

public static JScrollPane scrollPane;
public static MazePanel mazePanel;
private JMenuBar menuBar;
public static JButton startButton;


public Gui() {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    startButton = new JButton("START");
    startButton.addActionListener(new GuiActionListener());

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(startButton);

    mazePanel = new MazePanel();

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mazePanel);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    add(scrollPane);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
}

class RecursiveAlgorithm implements Runnable{

private int columns;
private int rows;
private int startX;
private int startY;

public RecursiveAlgorithm() {

    rows = Main.maze.length;
    columns = Main.maze[0].length;
}

private boolean findPath(int x, int y) {
    System.out.println("findPath("+ x + "," + y +")");
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            System.out.print(Main.maze[r][c]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    if (y < 0 || y >= rows) return false;
    if (x < 0 || x >= columns) return false;
    if (Main.maze[x][y] == 3) {
        Main.maze[x][y] = 5;
        Main.gui.mazePanel.repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (Main.maze[x][y] != 0)
        if (Main.maze[x][y] != 1) return false;
    Main.maze[x][y] = 5;
    Main.gui.mazePanel.repaint();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (goInDirectory(0, x, y)) return true;
    if (goInDirectory(1, x, y)) return true;
    if (goInDirectory(2, x, y)) return true;
    if (goInDirectory(3, x, y)) return true;
    Main.maze[x][y] = 4;
    Main.gui.mazePanel.repaint();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean goInDirectory(int index, int x, int y) {

    switch (Main.directionArray[index]) {
        case 0:
            if (findPath(x,y-1)) return true;
            break;
        case 1:
            if (findPath(x+1,y)) return true;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (findPath(x-1,y)) return true;
            break;
        case 3:
            if (findPath(x,y+1)) return true;
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

private void findStart() {

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {

            if (Main.maze[r][c] == 0) {

                startX = r;
                startY = c;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("Thread started");
    findStart();
    boolean pathFound = findPath(startX, startY);
    if (pathFound) {

        System.out.println("Path found");
    } else {

        System.out.println("Path NOT found!");
    }
}
}
```

Question 2 (offtopic): In my real code, im draws images on JPanel and overrides paint() instead of paintComponent() in MazePanel. And it's work fine for me. But when i try move code from paint() to paintComponent(), it's stop working (nothing is drawn on my MazePanel then). Here's code (works fine):

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    if(Main.mazeReady) {
        rows = Main.maze.length;
        columns = Main.maze[0].length;

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {

                g.drawImage(Main.maze[r][c].getGraphic(), 
                        c * TileGraphicsHandler.TILE_HEIGHT, 
                        r * TileGraphicsHandler.TILE_WIDTH, 
                        null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that way it's NOT working:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(Main.mazeReady) {
        rows = Main.maze.length;
        columns = Main.maze[0].length;

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {

                g.drawImage(Main.maze[r][c].getGraphic(), 
                        c * TileGraphicsHandler.TILE_HEIGHT, 
                        r * TileGraphicsHandler.TILE_WIDTH, 
                        null);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

}
```

Question 3 (offtopic): How to divide my RecursiveAlgorithm, so I can add to gui button "STEP FORWARD" and control my algorithm that way (by pousing alghoritm and move only one / few line(s) in my RecursiveAlgorithm)?

Comment: `public class MazePanel extends JPanel{ ..
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) { ..` should be `public class MazePanel extends JPanel{ ..
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g); ..` for any Swing based `JComponent`.  I.E. do custom painting in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method and leave the `paint(Graphics)` alone.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for that. I'll remember about MCVE and SSCCE. 
The way you wrote won't work. If I write everything in paintComponent() and leave paint() alone... It won't draw anything on JPanel that way.

Way that i presented here works fine until i try to redraw JPanel from RecursiveAlgorithm thread and pause it for X sec... And also Gui freeze  in that case.

Comment: How, specifically, won't it work?

Comment: Simply if I move code from paint() to paintComponent() after super.paintComponent(g), application stop drawning / showing anything on JPanel. No idea... Am I doing something wrong (probably)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've edited my question and added MCVE (as far as I understand whats that). I hope my problem is clear right now. Sorry for previous posts... ;)

Comment: To see something, remove the paint method with comments like this `/*
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    }*/`. Or better, just delete it.
By overriding that method to do nothing, the paint chain of the panel is broken.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks! Works fine, but that stil didnt solve my main problem with repainting JPanel from another thread...

Comment: Posts should really focus on one question at a time.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oh come on! I wrote that the remaining questions are offtopic. The main question is at the top and is consistent with the title... Sorry, but that's makes me crazy. I've tried so many things and this still not working.

Comment: *"I wrote that the remaining questions are offtopic"*  I didn't actually read the majority of the text in the question, but you mentioned in comment that using `paintComponent(Graphics)` 'did not work', so that was top most on my mind.  To be honest, after the loooong wait and comments to get an MCVE going, I've kind of lost enthusiasm for this entire thread.  Also, in my defense, the example was painting absolutely nothing to screen when I first saw it, and the obvious fix was to fix the paint chain.  Perhaps you should reorder your priorities, but if you don't (shrugs) ..no skin off my nose.

Comment: @AndrewThompson ok, nevermind. Thanks at all, for interesting in my topic and also for explain about overriding painting methods from `JComponent`. I'll remember that! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I can provide you with some basic advice.  The code base you attached is rather large and frankly, a bit messy.

1. Don't override the `paint()` method.  You've correctly overridden `paintComponent(...)`, but overriding the `paint()` method is incorrect and may cause problems.
2. You have a `MazePanel` class that has a handle to the `Tile[][]` for a given `Maze`.  Consider instead creating a `Maze` class that has the `Tile[][]`, and all associated state associated with a `Maze`, and then you can just have a reference to the `Maze` from a `MazePanel`.
3. Add a method to your `Maze` class that can take one single step towards the solution of a maze (e.g `stepTowardsSolution()`). It can return an enum or boolean that indicates whether it's done or not.
4. In `MazePanel`, have a method called `solve()` that does :

   ```
   while(maze.stepTowardsSolution() != done) {
       repaint();
       sleepABit();
   }
   ```

Comment: I'v got also maze in main class (i have to clean up code at the end), is it ok and enough (acording to your hint) to keep everywhere, where I need maze, reference to Main.maze? And any ideas how to divide my RecursiveAlgorithm to steps?

Comment: I would definately clean up the code so you construct only 1 maze, and refer to it wherever needed (e.g MazePanel).  As far as dividing your recusive algorithm up, you can write a method that takes a maze, and returns a maze it visits from the current maze.  Consider creating a class called MazeTransition that has a state (e.g done, solving) that has a reference to the maze you go to from the current maze